# please identify this 6 - pins smd with code Z17B

Tags: pcb-design, sensor, identification, surface-mount, symbol

[image]on the cover code Z17B with6 pins  bar on the numbers

[image: like this picture]

Comment: I will take a SWAG and say it appears to be: 17SZ Buffers,Non-Opposite Side 1 1 SC-70-5 Logic-Buffers, Drivers, Receivers, Transceivers RoHS

Comment: Look at the answers you got and learn from them. Make sure that you understand that we know what you know and not much more: Google can search inside PDFs. Learn how to use Google. How do you think we find those answers? It's not magic. Logos help direct the search, but ultimately it's either Google or the Windows/Spotlight search of the index of our own hard drive :)

Comment: ali - Hi (a) Why did you use the tag "sensor"? What evidence do you have that this device in your question is a sensor? Please edit the question to add that evidence. (b) FYI these are the current "[Component Identification Question Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6710)". The more information you can supply from that list (including details of the overall product functionality, photos of the PCB including surrounding components, details of whatever reverse-engineering you may have done etc.), the better the chances of identification. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this one. https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nc7wz17-d.pdf. Except for the B suffix

[image]

Comment: your Answer can not contain the code that in image

Comment: It does contain a partial match in both code and case size.  FYI Ali